# How to overwrite parent class init method, and use super to call grandparent init, all without editing parent? (python 3)

Tags: python-3.x

I've written a "child" class that inherits from the pytorch "DatasetFolder" class.

The full code for the dataset folder class is available here:
https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torchvision/datasets/folder.html#DatasetFolder

I'd like to overwrite the init method detailed there, and replace it with my own logic.
However, I'd still like to call the grandparent init.

As the parent class (datasetfolder) code is a part of an external package, I'd like to avoid editing it.

How can I overwrite the parent class init method, and still call the grandparent init, without changing the parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's kinda hacky, but the two ways to do this are to just directly call the grandparent version, or to lie to `super` and say you *are* the parent, causing it to be skipped when doing the search for the next `__init__` to call. So either do:

```
 class Child(Parent):
     def __init__(self, ...args...):
         GrandParent.__init__(self, ...args...)
         # ... rest of __init__ ...
```

or:

```
 class Child(Parent):
     def __init__(self, ...args...):
         super(Parent, self).__init__(...args...)
         # ... rest of __init__ ...
```

Comment: Calling the parent class directly works great, I was fixated on using super for no reason.
However the second option returns an error, super only seems to work for me if I put in the name of the child class where you put "parent"

Comment: @Idodo: Are you sure you inherited properly? The `super` hack works just fine (it's what `Parent` would do itself if you used `super` in `Parent` to invoke `GrandParent`'s `__init__`, and Python can't tell the difference between an invocation from within `Child` vs. `Parent`). Are you sure you actually declared `class GrandParent:`, `class Parent(GrandParent):` and `class Child(Parent):`?